# Delete key from python dictionary having specific format

Tags: python

Key column of my dictionary contain words such as
1. Performance_appraisal
2. Continuous_feedback etc
3. *_appraisal

I need to delete words which are similar to the third example. i.e containing *_ in it
How do I do that?

Comment: Please show an example of what you have tried, including an example of your data and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
def clean_dict(my_dict):
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        if '*_' in key:
            del my_dict[key]
            return clean_dict(my_dict)
```

Comment: This will not work in Python3 and will throw a `RuntimeError`

Comment: I've just tested it in Python 3.7.6 and it works

Comment: I see your edit now. Before your change, it would've throw an error :)

Comment: Yes indeed, it would have thrown a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`